# Css float issue

Tags: css, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/55Ruh/9/. Red box doesn't get bigger even if I enter text.

```
<div class="box" style="background: red">
    <div class="lefty">Text</div>
    <div class="righty">Text</div>
</div>    

.box {
    background: red;
    width: 229px;
    color: white;
}

.lefty {
    float: left;
}

.righty {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to put a little more effort into your question if you want anyone to put any effort into answering it.

Comment: maybe add a <br clear="all"/> after the two floating divs? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: Well, I posted jsFiddle, I thought that was enough, I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/55Ruh/10/

Float causes the element to get out of the flow of the document.

on parent element:

```
zoom: 1; /* IE fix */
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: @hey: no problem. There are several solutions to this problem. One of them is the comment of Atul Dravid, but this is the cleanest one. And best working one (I haven't found a better fix yet :) ).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a "clearing" div, a typical approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/apDU6/

Answer (score 1):

The container collapese when it has only floats inside. You need to clear it to expand it:

```
<div class="box" style="background: red">
    <div class="lefty">Text</div>
    <div class="righty">Text</div>
    <div class="clear"/>
</div>    

.box {
    background: red;
    width: 229px;
    color: white;
}

.lefty {
    float: left;
}

.righty {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the solution suggested by PeeHaa it does the trick

but for my experience you can simply set the container element's overflew to auto

it does the trick as well

Comment: Either `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`. They both do the trick. However in some situations you'll find out that `overflow: auto` will cause scrollbars to appear. And the `zoom: 1` is an IE fix.

Comment: amazingly right, yea the overflow causes scroll bars, so i used to play around with margins for ie6 and 7 to make it fit, but this is a great trick, thanks for the info